# Unable to render file larger than 4 Gigs in Sony Vegas 10

Tags: codec, vegas-pro

I have wasted over 8 hours trying to figure out what is wrong my program. I am trying to render a 30 minute file in high quality HD using the Main Concept codec, but as soon as it reaches 100% I get this error saying there was unknown error while creating the media file. Is this some sort of limitation to the codex or program? Is there a workaround?

Thanks.

Comment: question- have you tested to see if files under 4gb work? The error report you describe doesn't mention size. It could be the filesystem permissions...

Comment: If you are exporting to an external harddrive that's formatted as FAT32 you are unable to have files larger than 4GB. That's the only thing that comes to mind for me.

Comment: I have absolutely zero idea what went wrong, but I suspect it may been something with the actual file. Anyway I was able to render the file with no problem to .wmv format so it's all good. Thanks for the replies.

Comment: [This may be related](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757763%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Look under limitations. Whether Vegas Pro uses this "File Sink" or not, I don't know. If it does than this is an inherent issue with Vegas Pro on Win 7 or earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what went wrong but I was able to render it in .wmv format. Must have been something wrong with the file itself.